# Properly authenticating against WCF service in a Claims environment

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, wif, claims

SharePoint web applications in Claims authentication mode supports NTLM, but only through the following steps:

1. HTTP 302 redirect to a second location.
2. HTTP 401 challenge for NTLM auth
3. HTTP 401 verification
4. HTTP 302 redirect back to original location (service)

Can I write a custom behavior, channel factory or binding to handle this? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but isn't [c2WTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539739.aspx) supposed to solve this problem?

Comment: I think C2WTS is one possible route on the service side, if the authentication really is handled by the identitymodel libraries. The way I see it, the two main options are to either use claims for auth, or somehow disable claims for the one file / address, and let the service receive the NTLM header.. I have a feeling the former is better.

Answer (score 0):

What you have listed is the standard NTLM hand shake.

One way to avoid it is to use Kerberos instead of NTLM. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502594.aspx

Comment: If Kerberos works, that is one option, but judging from what I've seen in the IdentityModel source code, there would still be a redirect to the second location before the actual authentication takes place. It seems a basicHttpBinding with NTLM transport auth wouldn't be able to understand / pass the federation cookie #2 results in. But more pressing than that: I don't know how to make the WCF client move past the #1 which is actually a 403, rather than a 302, in SharePoint'ss case.